# Powershell not returning same on 2 different machines

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a question about Powershell in Windows 7.
I am running same version when checking `$PSVersionTable` on both machines but when running  `Get-WmiObject Win32_SerialPort` I get no results on one of them even though there is a Serial Adapter attached, the other one show lots of output in prompt.

My work pc is running Windows 7 Enterprise(The working one) and the other is running Windows 7 Pro.

Is that what is causing the trouble?

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                 
PSVersion                      3.0                                                                                                   
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                   
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                               
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444                                                                                       
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16481                                                                                        
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}                                                                                       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Thank in advance!

Br Mads

Comment: My suspicion would be a corrupt WMI repository. You should try repairing the repository. If that doesn't correct it my next suspicion would be that the manufacturer did not implement reporting correctly for that class or there is a corrupt driver issue. Updating the drivers **may** help.

Comment: did you try to run script with elevated privilege ?

Comment: I'm with EBGreen on this one, sounds like either a corrupted WMI repository which you can fix with instructions from [this link](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm)(use the vista instructions, they work on 7), or maybe a UAC issue on the Windows 7 Pro machine.

Comment: Can you try `change port` in an elevated cmd.exe command prompt on both machines ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enumerate serial ports from the `Win32_SerialPort` WMI class, without being an administrator. I would first go into **Device Manager**, and make sure that the serial port shows up there.

If it does not show up in **Device Manager** (as I suspect), then check the BIOS and make sure that the serial port option is enabled in the firmware.

Comment: Wow Thnk you all for very quick replys! It does show information under device manager so it is rekognizing mt device. I will try all of you r various suggestions. I will get back to you.

Comment: You can also use `wbemtest.exe` (built into Windows) to explore WMI, or one of the variety of third-party tools.